# Python selenium - clicking checkbox that also has a dropdown text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I wish to mark a checkbox, but the problem is that that text near the checkbox also incorporates a collapse-link, so whenever I try and click it, only the drop-down text is shown so the checkbox isn't being marked.
I've tried clicking the checkbox using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'example_text_positiond_next_to_checkbox')]").click()
```

but this, as mentioned, only clicks the text, which then proceeds to display the collapsed text

the HTML snippet is (and I hope I haven't missed any important part)

```
<label class="custom-control-label" 
for="customCheck1"><a class="collapse-link collapsed"
data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseInfo" role="button" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-controls="collapseExample">example_text_positiond_next_to_checkbox<span 
class="arrow"></span></a></label>
```

I've thought of somehow clicking some margin to the left of the text, but not quite sure how to do so.
any suggestions are welcomed!

that's the box:
[image]

Comment: is there a link to taht website

Comment: yes - https://corona.health.gov.il/en/green-pass/

Comment: it would be more helpful

Comment: added a link (there's also an English option), just note that it crashes constantly due to overdamand

Comment: please add the screenshot of the checkbox you are interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.get("https://corona.health.gov.il/en/green-pass/")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[for="customCheck1"]').click()
input()
```

you can use any attribute to find element the above locator with attribute 'for' will work. You can use xpath or css

**XPATH equalent:**

```
//*[@for="customCheck1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with css selector, as there is no direct way to inspect that checkbox in DOM.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#customCheck1.custom-control-input").click()
```

try below css.

```
input#customCheck1.custom-control-input
```

Comment: why cant' this be done with xpath ! `//input[@id="customCheck1" and contains[@class,"custom-control-input"]]` is the xpath equalent of the CSS

Comment: Go to that website > Open dev tools on chrome > CTRL + F
If you paste above xpath no element is selected, if you put css_selector you'll see that checkbox getting highlighted.

Comment: "Xpath will not work" and your xpath is wrong are two different statement

Comment: ::after is not Xpath notation it is CSS.

Such elements are called as pseudo elements.

Comment: `//input[@id="customCheck1" and contains(@class,"custom-control-input")]`

Comment: did you try this locator ?

Comment: @PDHide I copied your xpath from 1st comment, it did not work for me. (It is because line is cut after çustom- )

How did you derive this Xpath?
There is no straight forward way to identify this input in DOM.

Comment: use the new one the first one is wrong my mistake

Comment: `//input[@id="customCheck1" and contains(@class,"custom-control-input")]`

Comment: also you don't need all thos fancy locator as its uses unique id

Comment: `//*[@id="customCheck1"]`

Comment: I could find CSS easily, probably XPATH is derived from there. Anyway framework should be robust enough that analyst could through XPATH or CSS.

Both are correct.

Comment: `#customCheck1` this could be the css even if you go behind css . why to use such long css ?

Comment: "i can remove the down vote if you remove the statement "you can't use xpath" "

Comment: Removed. But I still hold my ground as there is no direct way to inspect that checkbox in DOM and derive that xpath. 

Comment: When uyou right click checkbox and click inspect it takes you to the label , and the input tag is above that and is hidden by the label tag so your click will be intercepted . so you cna inspect it

Comment: try running your code you will get click intercepted error